# remove asset border

Tags: python, pygame

I'm developing a game in pygame. I've a problem with some of my assets.
My assets are Transparents PNG but when i draw them on screen, i have a black border arround the drawings.

This is the asset:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZEtE.png)

And this is how it's drawn
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKPZz.png)

this is my code:

```
class Spritesheet:
    def __init__(self, file):
        self.sheet = pygame.image.load(file).convert_alpha()
    def get_sprite(self, x, y, width, height):
        sprite= pygame.Surface([width, height])
        sprite.blit(self.sheet, (0,0), ( x, y, width, height) )
        sprite.set_colorkey(BLACK)
        return sprite
class Hechizos(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
     self.groups = self.game.all_sprites
     pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
     self.image = self.graficos_hechizo['animacion'][0]
     self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
     self.rect.x = self.jugador.x * TILE_SIZE + self.ajuste_hechizo_x
     self.rect.y = self.jugador.y * TILE_SIZE + self.ajuste_hechizo_y
```

I also tried adding a pink background on the asset and using:
`self.image.set_colorkey((255,0,255))`

But the result is the same, but with Pink Borders

Comment: you need per-pixel alpha I assume not a color key

Comment: Thanks Aaron for your comment. i tried using
sprite= pygame.Surface([width, height], flags=pygame.SRCALPHA) 
and it worked

Comment: The tip-off was that the black border wasn't perfectly `(0,0,0)` color which was why it was not being considered transparent. Keyed color mode only has fully opaque or fully transparent, and it decides that for each pixel only if it *exactly* matches the key color.

Comment: Why not answer your own question?